# Worker configuration with make -j

Tags: gnu-make

I have a data processing pipeline with several stages, currently using a custom driver and pipeline framework. I'd really like to use something like `make`, but I would need to use the parallel capabilities for efficiency.

My question is, is there any configuration that could be done to the workers used by `make -j`?

For example, if the user runs `make -j8`, I'd like each of the 8 processes to use a slightly different environment.

Currently I have a custom setup using MATLAB, and I know MATLAB's parallel processing toolbox allows worker setup/teardown features.

Here's an example:

```
all: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9

t%:
    $APP args
```

Where `$APP` is different for every process spawned by `-j`.

Why would I want this? In this case, I have an `$APP` that can't run more than once simultaneously, so I want to create a pool of them: `$APP1`, `$APP2`, `$APP3`, etc. and distribute `make` jobs to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have in mind, but make will run a different recipe for each target that it builds, regardless of whether they're run in parallel or not.  Each one can have as many differences as you'd like to supply.  For example:

```
all: t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9

t%:
        TARGET=$@ run some command
```

The value of `TARGET` will be set to the name of the target that's being built.

Comment: Thanks, I added to the description to make it more clear.